# Is it possible for robocopy to always create destination structure if it's missing in monitor mode?

Tags: windows, robocopy

Setup:

- Several measurement devices are wired to a local computer.
- A python application runs on this computer to relay commands to the measurement devices.
- Measurement devices produce and store measurement files on a folder on the local computer.
- The python application opens robocopy in monitor mode to transfer these files:

`robocopy D:\source \\destination\a\b\c /MOV /NFL /NDL /NJH /NJS /MON:1`

`D:\source` and `\\destination` are constants. `a\b\c` is a folder structure read from information inside measurement files.

The problem:

- When robocopy first starts the `a\b\c` structure is created if it doesn't exist, which is fine.
- After some days, a user moves `a\b\c` from the network folder somewhere else for procesing (measurement files will not be produced during this time).
- Now that `a\b\c` is missing from the network folder robocopy will output the following message:

  ```
  ERROR 3 (0x00000003) Copying file D:\source\<filename>
  The system cannot find the path specified.
  ```

I have looked through the command line options for robocopy without finding anything regarding this.

Have I missed the option in the robocopy Microsoft Docs page? Do I have to manually check if the folder exists and have the python application create it?

Comment: Try the `/mot:1` option, [described](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) as : "/mot:<m> - Monitors the source, and runs again in m minutes, if changes are detected".

Comment: Unfortunately it's the same behaviour. It creates the structure at start, then if the structure is removed/renamed it fails with the next file with the same error 3.